# Creating AlertDialog before setting its buttons

Tags: android

I think I checked all of the related answers but none of those worked for me.

I have an action bar that has an option to change web URL, and that option opens an alert dialog.
The code changes the current page URL on first click.

The problem is that when I click on the option for the second time, the app crashes.
I tried using `dialog.dismiss()` or `dialog.close()` in the neutral button, but they don't work for the created `AlertDialog.Builder` so I tried to add `AlertDialog` which doesn't make much sense. 
I read that you should call `create()` method inside `onClick` positive button listener, but if I do that, I can't use the same alert dialog in the second button. I tried putting it outside the `actionbar` method and then initializing it inside the positive button but that closes the app on the second click.
Put it as final inside the case, before `setPositiveButton`, but then when i click the option in the menu, the buttons don't show, because they are set later in code. 
Also I am not sure if I should call the show() method on adWeb or webAlert. If I call it on adWeb, nothing is shown.
**This is the current code:**

```
case 0:
            webAlert.setMessage("Enter url");
            webAlert.setTitle("Replacing the web page");

            webAlert.setView(edittext);

            final AlertDialog adWeb = webAlert.create();
            webAlert.setPositiveButton("Submit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    if(edittext.getText().toString().contains("https") || (edittext.getText().toString().contains("http")))
                        wv.loadUrl(edittext.getText().toString());

                    wv.loadUrl("https:\\" + edittext.getText().toString());
                    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
                    wv.setWebViewClient(new Callback());

                }
            });

            webAlert.setNeutralButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    adWeb.dismiss();
                }
            });
            webAlert.show();
            return true;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should use adWeb for setNeutralButton, setPositiveButton and show methods

Comment: @ShashankUdupa But when i use the first 2 methods on adWeb i get an "Cannot resolve method..." error

Comment: move the setNeutralButton & setPositiveButton above webAlert.create() and use adWeb.show()

Comment: @ShashankUdupa but then i get "Cannot resolve symbol" on adWeb.dismiss() because the adWeb isn't initialized...

Comment: You don't need to do adWeb.dismiss(), clicking neutralButton automatically dismisses alert dialog

Comment: @ShashankUdupa  my app still crashes on second click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `webAlert.setView(edittext);`

This probably ought to be:

```
webView.setView(new EditText(context));
```

Or:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.my_edit_text);
webView.setView(editText);
```

If you can, try to create a new `View` for each new dialog.